# Load testing WCF service (hosted on IIS)

Tags: wcf, performance, iis, load-testing

What tools are there that I can test out a WCF service?

I am expecting allot of load so I want to have an idea how much a single server can handle.

Answer (score 20):

[WCFLoadTest](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFLoadTest) all the way. I've even talked to MS guys who swear by this tool.

Visual Studio also has some load testing tools available, but I cannot vouch for how well they do their job, nor can I say which versions of VS contain the load testing tools.

Comment: What about WCF services hosted in windows services ? Can WcfLoadTest help here at all ?

Answer (score 9):

I wrote my own tool ([WCFStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx)).  These are the features:

**General**:

◦Dynamically invoke and test WCF Services

◦Dynamically invoke and test Web services written in any language

◦Save your opened service and its test cases into a "project" which can be reloaded anytime

◦Dynamically invoke service methods even those containing complex data types

◦UI-based, dynamic editing of complex data types

◦Test multiple WCF and Web services within a single UI.

◦Multiple-tabbed interface

◦Basic and windows authentication

◦Test services sitting behind a proxy

◦Dynamically modify the URL endpoint of a WCF or Web service.

◦Dynamically edit the service binding.

**Functional Testing**:

◦Create functional test cases and save it as part of a project

◦Create and save functional test cases containing Expected results.

◦Graphically compare (side-by-side) the expected results with the actual response of a service.

**Performance Testing:**

◦Create performance test cases and save it as part of a project

◦Graphically display charts in real-time as the performance test progresses.

◦Configurable test parameters (# of Agents, Test duration, interval etc.).  You can    stress out your service as much as you want.

Check out the screenshot.

[image]
<sub>(source: [geekswithblogs.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20130131173625/http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/Erik/WcfStorm/WcfStormPerfTest.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I've just been using the Lite version of your tool, and was quite impressed. Very nice, thanks :)

Comment: What about WCF services hosted in windows services ? Can WcfLoadTest help here at all ?

Comment: @Mani his tool is not named WcfLoadTest its named WCFStorm.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But can it help in testing wcf services hosted in windows service?

Answer (score 3):

Start with this:

http://www.codeplex.com/WCFLoadTest

It doesn't do everything possible with WCF, but it is the best tool to start with. Worse comes to worse, it's not that hard to write manual invocation code with web services. They are much easier to load test than web sites.

Answer (score 1):

The SO-Aware test workbench makes things very easy with a rich visual experience. You can build a variety of tests and scenarios and run them very quickly.

http://www.tellagostudios.com/products/so-aware-test-workbench%E2%84%A2

Comment: I'm trying to install Express edition on W7 but the installer says I need to install IIS 6.0 compatibility mode, any idea how to do it on W7? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.soapui.org/ there's an open source and pro version you will need to tick download loadui, which is your load test bit.